# Ray-bounded plane intersection

Tags: c++, math, linear-algebra, intersection, raytracing

I'm trying to write a ray tracer in my freetime. Currently trying to do ray - bounded plane intersections.

My program is already working with infinite planes. I'm trying to work out the math for non-infinite planes. Tried to google, but all of the resources talk only about infinite planes.

My plane has a corner point (called position), from which two vectors (u and v) extend (their length correspond to the length of the sides). The ray has an origin and a direction.

First I calculate the intersection point with an infinite plane with the formula

`t = normal * (position - origin) / (normal * direction)`

The normal is calculated as a cross product of u and v.
Then with the formula

`origin + direction * t`

I get the intersection point itself.

The next step is checking if this point is in the bounds of the rectangle, and this is where I'm having trouble.

My idea was to get the relative vector `intersection - position` that is extending from the corner of the plane to the intersection point, then transform it to a new basis of u, normal and v then check if the lengths of the transformed vectors are shorter than the u and v vectors.

```cpp
bool BoundedPlane::intersect(const Vec3f &origin, const Vec3f &direction, float &t) const {
    t = normal * (position - origin) / (normal * direction);
    Vec3f relative = (origin + direction * t) - position;

    Mat3f transform{
        Vec3f(u.x, normal.x, v.x),
        Vec3f(u.y, normal.y, v.y),
        Vec3f(u.z, normal.z, v.z)
    };

    Vec3f local = transform.mul(relative);
    return t > 0 && local.x >= 0 && local.x <= u.x && local.z <= 0 && local.z <= v.z;

}
```

At the end I check if t is larger than 0, meaning the intersection is in front of the camera, and if the lengths of the vectors are inside the bounds. This gives me a weird line:

[image: weird line].

The plane should appear below the spheres like this:

[image: like this]

(this used manual checking to see if it appears correctly if the numbers are right).

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and if there's an easier way to check the bounds. Thanks in advance.

**Edit1:**

I moved the transformation matrix calculations into the constructor, so now the intersection test is:

```cpp
bool BoundedPlane::intersect(const Vec3f &origin, const Vec3f &direction, float &t) const {
    if (!InfinitePlane::intersect(origin, direction, t)) {
        return false;
    }

    Vec3f local = transform.mul((origin + direction * t) - position);

    return local.x >= 0 && local.x <= 1 && local.z >= 0 && local.z <= 1;
}
```

The transform member is the inverse of the transformation matrix.

Comment: What's "a weird line"? Do you have a failure case?

Comment: Added picture to the post. What do you mean by failure case? When the ray is not intersecting at all (in this case the function just returns false because of the t>0 condition)?

Comment: A failure case is a case in which the function gives the wrong results. That is, a bounded plane and ray that *should* intersect, but *don't,* or that *shouldn't* intersect, but *do.*

Comment: I'm still not sure what's your question. Are you asking for a concrete case with numbers?

Comment: A list of possible issues: 1) Are the vectors you pass into `Mat3f`'s constructor its rows or columns? - if they are rows then they should be the three basis vectors. 2) They should also be normalized, or you will need to account for scaling. 3) Since `local` is in the... *local* basis of the plane, it should be bound by `(|u|, |v|)` (or `(width, length)` if you choose to normalize `u, v`), not `(u.x, v.z)` which are coordinates in the *world* basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could I suggest another approach? Consider the frame with origin
`position` and basis vectors

```
u = { u.x, u.y, u.z }  
v = { v.x, v.y, v.z }  
direction = { direction.x, direction.y, direction.z}
```

**Step 1:** Form the matrix

```
M = {
      {u.x,  v.x,  direction.x},
      {u.y,  v.y,  direction.y},
      {u.z,  v.z,  direction.z} 
    }
```

**Step 2:** Calculate the vector `w`, which is a solution to the 3 x 3 system of liner equations

`M * w = origin - position`, i.e.

```
w = inverse(M) * (origin - position);
```

Make sure that `direction` is not coplanar with `u,  v`, otherwise there is no intersection and `inverse(M)` does not exist.

**Step 3:** if `0.0 <= w.x && w.x <= 1.0 && 0.0 <= w.y && w.y <= 1.0` then the line intersects the parallelogram spanned by the vectors `u,  v` and the point of intersection is

```
w0 = { w.x, w.y , 0 };

intersection = position + M * w0;
```

else, the line does not intersect the parallelogram spanned by the vectors `u,  v`

The idea of this algorithm is to consider the (non-orthonormal) frame `position,  u, v, direction`. Then the matrix `M` changes everything in the coordinates of this new frame. In this frame, the line is vertical, parallel to the "z-"axis, the point `origin` has coordinates `w`, and the vertical line through `w` intersects the plane at `w0`.

**Edit 1:** Here is a templet formula for the inverse of a 3x3 matrix:

If original matrix M is

```
a  b  c

d  e  f

g  h  i
```

inverse is

```
(1 / det(M)) * { 
                 {e*i - f*h,     c*h - b*i,     b*f - c*e},

                 {f*g - d*i,     a*i - c*g,     c*d - a*f},

                 {d*h - e*g,     b*g - a*h,     a*e - b*d},
                }
```

where

```
det(M) = a*(e*i - f*h) + b*(f*g - d*i) + c*(d*h - e*h)
```

is the determinant of M.

So the inversion algorithm can be as follows:

Given

```
M = {
      {a,  b,  c},
      {d,  e,  f},
      {g,  h,  i},
    }
```

1. Calculate

```
inv_M = { 
           {e*i - f*h,     c*h - b*i,     b*f - c*e},

           {f*g - d*i,     a*i - c*g,     c*d - a*f},

           {d*h - e*g,     b*g - a*h,     a*e - b*d},
         };
```

2. Calculate

```
det_M = a*inv_M[1][1] + b*inv_M[2][1] + c*inv_M[3][1];
```

3. Return inverse matrix of M

```
inv_M = (1/det_M) * inv_M;
```

**Edit 2:** Let's try another approach in order to speed things up.

**Step 1:** For each plane, determined by the point `position` and the two vectors `u` and `v`, precompute the following quatntities:

```
normal = cross(u, v); 

u_dot_u = dot(u, u);

u_dot_v = dot(u, v);

v_dot_v = dot(v, v); // all these need to be computed only once for the u and v vectors

det = u_dot_u * v_dot_v - u_dot_v * u_dot_v; // again only once per u and v
```

**Step 2:** Now, for a given line with point `origin` and direction `direction`, as before, calculate the intersection point `int_point` with the plane spanned by `u` and  `v`:

```
t = dot(normal,  position - origin) / dot(normal, direction);

int_point = origin + t * direction;

rhs = int_point - position;
```

**Step 3:** Calcualte

```
u_dot_rhs = dot(u, rhs);

v_dot_rhs = dot(v, rhs);

w1 = (v_dot_v * u_dot_rhs - u_dot_v * v_dot_rhs) / det;

w2 = (- u_dot_v * u_dot_rhs + u_dot_u * v_dot_rhs) / det;
```

**Step 4:**

```
if (0 < = w1 && w1 <= 1 && 0 < = w2 && w2 <= 1 ){
   int_point is in the parallelogram;
}
else{
   int_point is not in the parallelogram;
}
```

So what I am doing here is basically finding the intersection point of the line `origin,  direction` with the plane given by `position,  u,  v` and restricting myself to the plane, which allows me to work in 2D rather than 3D. I am representing

```
int_point = position + w1 * u + w2 * v;

rhs = int_point - position = w1 * u + w2 * v
```

and finding `w1` and `w2` by dot-multiplying of this vector expression with the basis vectors `u` and `v`, which results in a 2x2 linear system, which I am solving directly.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up having the original transformation matrix, but your post explained me that my maths was off and i had to inverse the matrix. It's working now but very slowly compared to before, the simple scene in the question took me around 2 seconds to calculate, with 4 planes it takes about 20-30 seconds.

Comment: @DanielSmith Just out of curiosity, is it the matrix inversion that slows it down? What algorithm are you using for matrix inversion (I guess it is part of the library)?

Comment: Yes, I think it's the inversion that slows it down. I'm using a self-written linear algebra header (I tried Eigen 3 but it slowed down the calculations by a lot). Right now it's just a hardcoded 3x3 inverse that I wrote to check if your answer gives me the correct result. I'm going to redo it.

Comment: @DanielSmith Technically, you do not need to invert the matrix, you just need to solve the system of linear equations in step 2. Maybe we can think of a fast solver for the liner system instead of inverting.

Comment: So far I tried to avoid any libraries because they tend to be too slow for this much calculations and it's been a few years since I had linear algebra in uni so inverse sounds easier to be done than a linear equation solver. I'm open to everything though.

Comment: @DanielSmith Maybe we can just write directly the inverse of a matrix, by using a templet formula, or we could use Gauss or Gauss-Jordan elimination algorithm:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Comment: I just realized, as I'm using the vectors u, normal and v for the transformation matrix, I dont need to calculate the inverse for every intersection test, because the matrix is only dependent on the plane. I've moved the calculations into the constructor, so the intersection test only requires a few minor operations (edit 1). However this didn't lead to any gains in runtime.

Comment: @DanielSmith I added a proposed algorithm for inversion of a matrix. I have to say that with your approach, you are calculating a lot of stuff, which you could circumvent. You are calculating a cross product for the normal (which is roughly 2/3 of a determinant), which you do not really need, then  calculating an intersection point and then you are calculating the inverse of a 3x3 matrix. That is why I proposed the method above, because I calculate the intersection point and the check for it being in the parallelogram by calculating only one inverse matrix.

Comment: @DanielSmith Oh, and to save a bit more, the check can be just ```(w.x)*(w.x) <= 1 && (w.y)*(w.y) <= 1```

Comment: Forgot to mention, the inversion function is exactly written as you proposed. I will look into faster ways of inverting functions when I get there.
As for the other calculations, the normal is calculated once in the cosntructor, and is needed for the lights anyway, so it's not additional computation.
I used my version (u, normal, v) of the basis vectors because they are only dependent on the plane itself, therefore it's enough to calculate the inverse only once. If you swap the normal for the direction of the ray, you need to calculate the inverse for each ray, which should be slower.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and insights too!

Comment: @DanielSmith I added Edit 2, which avoids 3 x 3 matrices and it is much more direct, while accounting for the information already available. Feel free to try it and let me know if it is faster. I hope I did not mix up the math, but if something is off, let me know.

Comment: I tried it, and as it turns out there wasn't any speed gains (none whatsoever). This leads me to believe the slowdown is somewhere else. I will probably end up benchmarking each part of the rayracer to localize the issue. Let me know if you have any thoughts.